# Navigating to child categories with keeping a path in the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, blazor

I am trying to do navigation in my client-server application. I'm trying to make a small online catalog

I want that when navigating through categories, the path is displayed in the URL:

```
https://test.com/
https://test.com/controllers
https://test.com/controllers/for-media-screens

https://test.com/
https://test.com/phones
https://test.com/phones/nokia
```

And if you know the whole path except the last link, you can write the `@page "/phones/{model}"` in the Razor component

Then what to do when the whole path is unknown?
The `@page` directive cannot contain an array with values that will be expanded into a link.

Do you have any ideas how this can be organized?

I thought cascading parameters would work, but they don't work with `@page`.

I also thought that it was possible to store the full path to the product in the database, but I'm not sure that this is the best solution.

UPD:
@KirkWoll, In principle, all categories are unknown

Well, look what I mean
There can be a huge number of categories and subcategories of different levels:

`https://site.ru/1-level/2-level/.../n-level/product`

When we moved to the 1-level directory, our URL looks like `/1-level`. From there we can go to the next level of categories and the URL will look like `/1-level/2-level`. And so on.

That is, we know specifically only the domain

If, relatively speaking, we had only 1 category on our site without any subcategories, then we could simply strictly set its URL in the page directive of the category page template, for example `@page "/category"`, and write `@page "/category/{Id:int}` in the product template

And the question is how to write the code in which the previous URL will be passed so that the link looks like `https://site.ru/1-level/2-level/.../n-level/product`

That is, I need, if it were possible, to write in the template of the category `@page "/{?1}/{?2}.../{n}"`, and in the product template @page `"/{?1}/{?2}.../{n}/{Id:int}"`

Comment: "Then what to do when the whole path is unknown?"  What is an example of such a path?

Comment: @KirkWoll, Hi! I have updated the content of the question in the post. Read it, please

Comment: Thank you, your explanation of n-level deep paths has clarified your question for me.

Comment: Have you looked at ["catch all" (i.e. wildcard) routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#catch-all-route-parameters-1)?  In particular, "For the URL `/catch-all/this/is/a/test` with a route template of `/catch-all/{*pageRoute}`, the value of `PageRoute` is set to `this/is/a/test`."

Comment: Damn, I read this documentation, but apparently due to fatigue, since I was trying to find a solution to the problem for a long time, I did not notice this paragraph in the text!

Thank you very much for your help, I am very grateful!

Everything turned out to be much easier than I expected! :D

If you make a post with this answer, I will be happy to mark it as a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to achieve something a bit out of the box in terms of supporting routes with arbitrary levels of depth.  One way to do that would be to use the ["catch all" routing facility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#catch-all-route-parameters-1).  It's basically a way to consume all possible routes given a prefix.  From the docs:

```
@page "/catch-all/{*pageRoute}"

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string PageRoute { get; set; }
}
```

> For the URL `/catch-all/this/is/a/test` with a route template of `/catch-all/{*pageRoute}`, the value of `PageRoute` is set to `this/is/a/test`.

With that, you should be able to consume `PageRoute`, parse it, and do what you need to support your routing requirements.